# Error Running localhost in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to run an application so I can test it locally but currently I am having issues.

I am using gradle and following this tutorial

https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

However, I finish the tutorial and run this command :

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

The application starts but I can't hit the end point.

It throws the following error:

```
    Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Dec 16 16:25:06 GMT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Any idea how to fix this?

```
 package conf;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 */

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Greeting Class

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

/**
 */

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your code with the complete example code "gs-serving-web-content/complete" folder in the [zip file](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content.git)?

Comment: I did it from scratch so I am not checking the code in the zip file.

Comment: By checking with the completed example, you will be able to see what you did wrong.

Comment: I found out that the reason behind this is because I have classes in different packages, however I was wondering if it was possible to have the Application class scan other packages, as I want to have separate packages depending on their purpose.

Comment: I don't think that's entirely possible. You need to follow Java and Spring standard in order to have it work. Here's some guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because of your package structure. Based on the code you've given, your `Application` class can't see `GreetingController` because they are in sibling packages. `@SpringBootApplication` needs to be able to component scan same package and child packages. It can't see sibling packages. So `GreetingController` never gets wired up.

Won't work:

```
com.conf.Application
com.controller.GreetingController
```

Will work:

```
com.conf.Application
com.conf.controller.GreetingController
```

Comment: Thank you Gregg, I'll try the proposed solution, however I want to have separate packages depending on the type of class. Is it there a way to have Application scan all the other packages(including controller package)?

Comment: Yes, you would have to include the `@ComponentScan` annotation which _should_ override the one that `@SpringBootApplication` is providing and you can control what is being scanned and where.